# How to load Bootstrap-Vue first using webpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-vue

I previously built an Electron application without any framework and am in the process of converting it to Vue.js. I am using Bootstrap and found Bootstrap-Vue. Following their guide, I imported the css files in my `app.js` file:

```js
import Vue                                               from 'vue'
import App                                               from './App.vue'
import router                                            from './router'
import store                                             from './store'
import {BootstrapVue, DropdownPlugin, BootstrapVueIcons} from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(DropdownPlugin)
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)
```

The problem is that bootstrap and bootstrap-vue get packed last by webpack and therefore override all my other styles. Is there anything I can do so that webpack packs bootstrap first, then everything else?

Comment: Show your `webpack configuration` in `vue.config.js`

Comment: @BadPiggie I don't have that file, I haven't done any configuration. I created the project using Vue CLI and I just know it's using webpack but I haven't changed anything.

Comment: It seems, You need to configure webpack. Refer this link https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration

Comment: I ended up removing the imports from `app.js` and just imported the CSS files manually within my `App.vue`, as I didn't find any option in webpack to do what I want.